# Whats the angular equivalent to Vue's beforeMount?

Tags: angular, angular8

Is there a beforeMount (Vue) equivalent in Angular. 
Maybe not as a lifecycle hook but as a conventional technique or something. What i mean is wheres the correct place to make the stuff that you traditionally do in beforeMount like fetching data or to consume store. Thank you

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 0):

A safe equivalent on Vue's `beforeMount` would be `ngAfterViewInit`.

As stated [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence)

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.

But for fetching data and consuming store, as well as using `@Input` properties, it's common, safe, and correct to use `ngOnInit`.

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.

If you want to use `@ViewChild` or access route state, it's better to use `ngAfterViewInit`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Vue.js docs (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount):

> Called right before the mounting begins: the `render` function is about to be called for the first time.

From the Angular 8 docs (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence):

> **ngOnInit()**

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the
> data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input
> properties.
>
> Called once, after the first `ngOnChanges()`.

It's called only once and before the rendering of the template (`ngAfterViewInit` or `ngAFterContentInit`)

For your concern about **where to fetch initial data**, again from the docs (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit):

> An ngOnInit() is a good place for a component to fetch its initial
> data.

Therefore, Angular's `ngOnInit` seems to be the equivalent of `beforeMount` of Vue.js